# Autowire giving null object in spring boot utility class

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to display some information from the database on the thymeleaf page using Custom dialect, however in the utility class I am getting the autowired repository as null.

This is my thymeleaf code

And this is utility class

@Autowired(required=true)
    private UserRepository userRepository;

```
public String getUserFullName(String useUsername){

    String fullname = "";

    if(useUsername != null && useUsername.length() > 0){
        User user = userRepository.findByUseUsername(useUsername);
        if(user != null){

            String profession = user.getUseProfession();
            if(profession == null || profession.length() < 1) {
                fullname = fullname + user.getUseSurname() + ", " + user.getUseFirstname();
            }
            else {
                fullname = fullname + user.getUseSurname() + ", " + user.getUseFirstname() + " (" + profession + ")";
            }
        }
    }
    return fullname;
}
```

And I am adding the utility class in dialect like this

```
  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalExpressionObjects(IProcessingContext ctx) {
    Map<String, Object> expressions = new HashMap<>();
    expressions.put("fullnameUtil", new FullNameUtil());
    return expressions;
  }
```

I am getting the userRepository as null.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by autowiring the utility class in the custom dialect

@Autowired(required=true)
      private FullNameUtil fullNameUtil;

```
  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalExpressionObjects(IProcessingContext ctx) {
    Map<String, Object> expressions = new HashMap<>();
    expressions.put("fullnameUtil", fullNameUtil);
    return expressions;
  }
```